# Генерирование баркодов EAN-13

Tags: python, python-3.x, barcode

### Тема

Есть ли какая-то библиотека на *Python* что-бы генерировать штрих коды?

[image]

### Особенности

***python-barcode*** не подходит, мне нужен генератор который будет генерировать точно такие-же штрих коды, может быть есть у кого скрипт на подобную генерацию, либо кто-то знает подобную библиотеку ***python-barcode***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427243/how-to-generate-barcode-in-python-3-7

Тут решение ровно вашей проблемы, вроде бы...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Можете перевести ответ, указав данную ссылку на английский SO.

Comment: ImSoBad, я нашёл алгоритм и немного не дождавшись начал писать свою свою библиотеку и получилось всё так-же как и на той ссылке вопроса, спасибо.